# Getting unwanted log messages using logback 1.1 + tomcat 7 + spring 3.x

Tags: tomcat, logback

I'm getting unwanted log messages in my log file from packages such as org.apache.axiom and org.apache.axis2, just for example. I just switched my web app from log4j to logback. My tomcat server is still configured to use log4j. Can anybody educate me as to why? Are these messages coming from Tomcat? Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the relevant code:

web.xml

```
<web-app .....>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>ch.qos.logback.ext.spring.web.LogbackConfigListener</listener-class>
    <listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>logbackConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>file:/opt/myapp/logback-server.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
       <param-name>logbackExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
       <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Other Spring configuration -->
<web-app>
```

logback-server.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="MAIN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/usr/local/logs/server.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter>
           <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %p | %c %M | %m%n
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/usr/local/logs/server.log.%d</fileNamePattern>
    <appender>

    <appender name="TRACE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/usr/local/logs/server-trace.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter>
           <level>TRACE</level>
           <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
           <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} | %p | %c %M | %m%n
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>/usr/local/logs/server-trace.log.%d</fileNamePattern>
    <appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="MAIN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="TRACE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was my mis-understanding.

This is happening because my root logger's level was DEBUG so all other packages not specified in the file are logged at the DEBUG level and higher. Changed root level definition to:

```
<root level="WARN">
  <appender-ref ref="MAIN"/>
  <appender-ref ref="TRACE"/>
</root>
```